# PHP vs. C CGI for small web service

Tags: php, c, web-services, comparison, fastcgi

I am creating a small web service which will only be accessed by machines, not users that simply takes a query string and makes a few MySQL queries. I decided to code this in PHP because it is simple and easy to write and does its job well. My boss however, wants we to write it as a CGI in C (using FastCGI) because he says it will be faster and use less memory. I'm not so keen on this idea for a few reasons:

- The MySQL API for C seems to have a lot more calls than the equivalent PHP and need a lot more error handling.
- String manipulation in C is somewhat complicated and messy.
- The code in C is almost 3 times as long as the equivalent code in PHP and looks rather messy, with lots of error handling.

But that's just my opinion. What other factors do I need to take in to account? Is C the best tool for this job? Or is PHP?

Comment: I think you should write your own HTTP server in assembly. That will be teh fastestest.

Comment: why not benchmark the two and show your boss the result? use fastcgi for the php as well. take into consideration expected use (20 req/s? 100?), play around with the number of fastcgi workers, etc

Comment: Your boss is probably too stupid to tell the difference, so just go ahead and code it in PHP and tell him it's C. Win-win.

Comment: Is there a need for the performance benefit that you would get from C that outweighs the gained maintainability of the PHP solution?

Comment: If you only compare languages, C is more maintainable. It's been around longer, there are more C programmers on the globe (by most statistics you can find via search machines), C has less keywords (32 vs 65 in php if you go by their official docs) to learn, is more extensible (you can stuff with C you can't with php), ... Really, there is no _objective_ benefit of PHP i can think of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some points about this:

- It's much easier to implement any web
  service in PHP rather than C, because
  PHP is a language designed to work
  online and C is a general language.
- C is compiled and this makes it much faster than PHP programs, but if you are really worried about optimization (your program consumes a lot of resources and your hardware is very limited) you can use PHP "accelerators" that compiles the source ([for example](http://eaccelerator.net/))
- Access to databases is equal penalized in both languages, so if your program has to access a lot to DB, it will have a similar performance.
- The more important: the boss is the boss :)

Comment: It is not accurate that "Access to databases is equal penalized in both languages" because some Web frameworks use asynchronous calls which will allow slow DB requests not harm performance. The "general language" must be balanced with C's much lower learning curve than PHP (which is an enormous language with thousands of functions to learn).

Comment: -1 php "accelerators" like the given example don't compile php. Most they do is cache the transformed opcodes, and they may even optimize some stuff, but they don't compile php into machine code, never ever. I also agree that C is way simpler than PHP (been doing php for 6 years now and C for more more than 10)

Answer (score 3):

If speed is your (or your boss's) concern, [check out the G-WAN server](http://gwan.com/), which allows allows you to write C scripts. There are some [MySQL samples in the forum](http://forum.gwan.com/index.php?p=%2Fsearch&Search=mysql). It'll be **much faster** than FastCGI (which has to cross process boundaries via sockets).

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, if most processing is made by MySQL, there is no need to write this code in C, because difference is negligible, but if there is much processing will be made by your code, it makes sense to listen to your boss and make it in C

Answer (score 1):

Ask your boss if it wouldn't be better if you used C++.

- Remind him about the maintainability of the code, and that with C++, you can introduce less bugs, at the price of just little speed.
- Remind him that the "time" needed for fixing or improving software is "included" in the "execution time" - the time you'd have the services suffer because of a little mistake.

And try [fastcgi++](http://www.nongnu.org/fastcgipp/). You've also got [boost](http://www.boost.org/) and other libraries which can help you do the boring stuff faster, and concentrate on WHAT MATTERS.

And if the application does lots of calculations, it is a good idea to make it in C / C++.

- Otherwise remind your boss that usually, no matter the language, the application won't be slowed down by computations, but by "waiting for resources" - waiting for the disk or waiting for the database are the most prevalent ones - *which happens no matter the language*.
- Remind your boss that for the speed, you can get about 10-60% improvement by using [apc](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php).

If he simply doesn't want, then you have two choices:

- quit the job
- do as he asks you to

**Why C++, and not C**

It is true that with good coding conventions, you can write manageable code in C too.

But with C, you still have the verbosity of error handling, as opposed to exceptions, of NUL-terminated strings, of maps or what not. I love C too more than C++, but let's face it: 
*here is not about the language, it's about the mentality of a despot (the boss) who needs to be fought with arguments and learn to lend an ear to his employees.*

Comment: If you follow good coding practices, both languages are maintainable languages.

Comment: With C, you still have the verbosity of error handling, as opposed to exceptions, of NUL-terminated strings, of maps or what not. I love C too more than C++, but let's face it: here is not about the language, it's about the mentality of a despot (the boss) who needs to be fought with arguments and learn to lend an ear to his employees.

Comment: Remember Daniel talks about a "small web service". I agree that C++ is more maintainable when you want to implement a really big app, but for a small service any language is maintainable and C++ in my opinion don't offers any advantatge in this sense.

Comment: C++ may have its uses, but it does not match the question, which criteria is "C" because it is small and fast.

Comment: There's also many things which become problematic with C++ in contrast to C, like RAI for example. What if you have a problem with acquiring memory when doing new Whatever(), or when a line in the constructor fails for whatever reason? And if your destructors aren't called? (most people don't know that, but your destructors aren't sure to be called!)

Answer (score 0):

Both tools are ok. If your boss wants C, made it in C.

Answer (score 0):

You got no choice because your boss want it. Unless you can't code in C then just C it.

Answer (score 0):

Your app is most likely I/O bound. So it won't even be noticeable faster in C.

Answer (score -1):

shudder... You should leave the company. A boss shouldn't be allowed to micormanage the workers... unless he's also the programming guru of the company :)

Comment: @downvoter: yes, you're a boss yourself and you can't handle the truth :)

Comment: -1 This totally doesn't answer the question. It's not about liking the answer or not - it just simple doesn't answer it.